# Stop/Start Kafka Consumer/Producer Stream in Local Execution Mode

Tags: apache-flink

Setup:

- Java 8
- Flink 1.2 (Mac OSX)
- Kafka 0.10.0 (VirtualBox/Ubuntu)
- FlinkKafkaConsumer010
- FlinkKafkaProducer010

Created a simple example program to consume 1M message from one Kafka topic and produce to another - running in local execution mode.  Both topics have 32 partitions.

When I let run from start to finish, it consumes and produces all message.  If I start and then stop (SIGINT) before it is completed, then restart again the producer only receives a subset of the original 1M messages.

I have confirmed my offsets for the consumer and it read all 1M messages.

```
final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = 
    StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
env.setParallelism(32);
env.enableCheckpointing(1000L, CheckpointingMode.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

--

```
producer.setFlushOnCheckpoint(true);
producer.setLogFailuresOnly(false);
```

In local execution mode is this expected?  Do I need to enable savepoints to stop and restart a stream job?  I appears the producer is not committing all the messages when this happens.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, on subsequent runs, it only receives a subset of the messages because the `FlinkKafkaConsumer` is using the committed offsets in Kafka as the starting positions. Currently, the only way to avoid this right now in the releases (up to `1.2.0` as of now) is to always assign a new `group.id`. In the next release, there will be new options for this: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/kafka.html#kafka-consumers-start-position-configuration.

As a side note, please also note that the committed offsets in Kafka are not used at all for the exactly-once processing guarantees in Flink. Flink only relies on the checkpointed offsets for that. More details on this can be found in the Flink Kafka connector docs in the link above.